# How to call a fileScanner in a methods parameter

Tags: java, file

I am currently working on a project and I would like to use a fileScanner in a methods parameter. I am sorry if this is a simple fix but I could not get it to work and I searched online and on here and found nothing. Here is my code, thanks in advance!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FileScan
{
      private Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(new File(" "));

      public fileLoader(Scanner fileScan)
      {


      }
}
```

When I compile I either can not put the brackets in the parameter for fileLoader or I get an error that tells me that it can not find class "File".

Comment: Is that all of your code? Does it import java.io.File somewhere?

Comment: @NilsH Yes that is all I have for now, I completely forgot about importing java.io, thank you the reminder. To throw the exception it has to be in a class that has a main method though right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you just want a default constructor, then your code is fine except that your function definition is not valid in java-- you must have a return type or void.

```
public void fileLoader(Scanner fileScan)
```

or

```
public MyReturnType fileLoader(Scanner fileScan)
```

Comment: I want the constructor to take in the file as the user enters it and then I will store the info in an array, It seems fine however I keep getting errors!

Comment: You can't initialize the `Scanner` before having the file path.  So, you can pass the path or ask the user for the path and then initialize or reinitialize it in your method.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, I will try something along that route now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class FileScan {

               private Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(new File(" "));

            fileLoader(fileScan);


        }



        public static void fileLoader(Scanner fileScan) {


        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have more errors in your unfinished code:

```
Default constructor cannot handle exception type FileNotFoundException thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit constructor
```

You will have to move the initialisation of private fileScan variable into a constructor and there catch exceptions:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FileScan
{

      private Scanner fileScan;

      FileScan()
      {
          try {
              fileScan = new Scanner(new File(" "));
          } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }

      public void fileLoader(Scanner fileScan)
      {

      }
}
```

The second error is that you didnt define any return type to fileLoader method, so i've temporarily added `void`.

Comment: this seems unnecessarily complex, if it works it works however.